# DropdownListFor selected value not selecting in the rendered html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an extension method that I'm trying to use where you can use an enum property to create   a dropdown list, and set the selected item:

```
public enum DefaultEnumSelectItemOptions
{
    AddDefaultItemIfEnumIsZero,
    ZeroEnumIsDefaultItem
}
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this object enumObj, DefaultEnumSelectItemOptions option = DefaultEnumSelectItemOptions.AddDefaultItemIfEnumIsZero)
{
    var asEnum = Enum.Parse(enumObj.GetType(), enumObj.ToString());
    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumObj.GetType());
    var dataItems = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
    dataItems.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Select One", -1));
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        int enumValue = (int)values.GetValue(i);
        if (enumValue == 0)
        {
            if (option != DefaultEnumSelectItemOptions.AddDefaultItemIfEnumIsZero)
            {
                dataItems.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(values.GetValue(i).ToString(), enumValue));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dataItems.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(values.GetValue(i).ToString(), enumValue));
        }
    }
    var selectedItemValue = (int)enumObj;
    if (selectedItemValue == 0 && option == DefaultEnumSelectItemOptions.AddDefaultItemIfEnumIsZero)
    {
        selectedItemValue = -1;
    }
    return new SelectList(dataItems, "Item2", "Item1", selectedItemValue);
}
```

A model looks like this:

```
public enum PropertyTypes
{
    Unknown=0,
    Vehicle,
    Other
}

[DataContract]
public class Property : ClaimEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public PropertyTypes PropertyType { get; set; }

    public Property()
    {
        this.PropertyType = PropertyTypes.Vehicle;
    }
}
```

Finally the view looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyType, Model.PropertyType.ToSelectList())
```

When I set a breakpoint in the extension method, it appears to be correct, but the selected option is not appearing in the html.

[image: dropdown issue]

What am I doing wrong?

**edit** I changed it to use the `SelectListItem` as suggested, however I still am not seeing the value selecting:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply constructing the `SelectListItem` elements manually instead of using `Tuple<string, int>`? It has a `Selected` property which may solve this issue for you.

Comment: @Tejs Actually no. Hmm. One moment.

Comment: I thought the same Tejs.

Comment: @Tejs, Berat I made the changes as suggested, but it still isn't working. See new screen shot in edit.

Comment: I also changed it to a simple @Html.DropDownList("",...) and it still isn't rendering the selected item. What is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm actually running into this exact problem myself and discovered that the DropDownListFor (and DropDownList) helpers are a little too smart for their own good.

*Even if* you pass in a set of `SelectListItem` with one of them `Selected = true`, the helper will actually evaluate your model, do a `Convert.ToString()` on it, and attempt to match the value. If it doesn't find the value it will select nothing.

Personally I believe this is a major mistake in MVC, one that they do not appear to be correcting in MVC4. It is a completely bogus assumption on their part that that the `ToString()` method of an object would match the value (rather than the display text) in a dropdown.

edit: as for ways to fix this...

1. Change your `ToString()` method to return the value and figure out a different way to get your display text.
2. Since you're using an enum, you could just the string version for both your value and your display text. It will still bind fine.
3. Build your own dropdown

Comment: added actual solutions. If you discover a more clever method please comment here because I'd actually really love to hear it! I'm doing doing #1, myself.

Comment: What do you mean by `Change your ToString() method` ?

Comment: Oh I think I see what your getting at. I'm storing the actual enum values, 0,1,2 ect and it's doing a string comparision, and "Vehicle" != "1". Right?

Comment: Exactly. I forgot you were using an enum, so you can just use the string for your value instead of the int. Then it should match up fine, and binding will still work.

Comment: I just tried that, and it doesn't look like the binding is working anymore, still looking into it.

Comment: Sratch that, the new dropdown was not in the right div for the jQuery serilizer to pick it up. I move it to the right spot and its all working now.

Comment: I went with your `#1` as I don't have the time to waste being clever right now, and just need it to work! Thanks so much for the insight into the drop down helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach for creating my dropdown if anyone is interested, it works but might not be a clever way to do it since i am new to MVC. u need to check for firstelement is its enum value corresponds to any valid enum and push it in the select list method overload but i am in a rush so not doing that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> modelExpression, string firstElement)
        {
            var typeOfProperty = modelExpression.ReturnType;
            if (!typeOfProperty.IsEnum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not an enum", typeOfProperty));
            }

            Dictionary<int, string> KeyValuePair = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            Array EnumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeOfProperty);
            foreach (var item in EnumValues)
            {
                KeyValuePair.Add((int)item, item.ToString());
            }

            var selectList = new SelectList(KeyValuePair, "Key", "Value");
            return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(modelExpression, selectList, firstElement);
        }
    }
```

and used it in my page as

```
Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.AccountType, ContextConstants.defaultSelectionString)
```